# Dropdown multilevel hover issue in IE, firefox

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, superfish

I have used superfish for dropmenu , but having issues when rendering in IE 8,9 and Firefox, It works fine on safari and chrome, On hovering the products , the anchor text moves up , I have spent hours on it by modifying css with no success, can anyone assist me , where I am getting it wrong, below is the website :

[test-website](http://www.teamlemon.co.uk/) The hover effect can be found on product sub-list.

```
.sf-menu li a
{
    float: none;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 11px;    

    height: 23px;

    font-weight: bold;

}

.sf-menu li a:hover
{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 0px !Important;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px ;
    float: left;


}
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Change     `line-height: 20px;` to     `line-height: 24px;`

```
.sf-menu li a:hover {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 0 !important;
    line-height: 24px;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

EDIT. Target the nested `li`

```
.sf-menu ul li ul li a:hover {
       padding: 0 0 0 20px;
       line-height: 20px;
}
```

You may need to play with these values.

Answer (score 0):

Your submenu has no point of reference from where to drop down on and you're specifying the container of the submenu as absolute as well as the submenu `ul` itself as well, i'm surprised it even works at all in Chrome, try this to fix it:

```
.quiklinks li {
    position:relative;
}
```

Under your **jquery.superfishmenu.css** stylesheet, fix the following:

Remove the `position:absolute` rule on the following class:

```
.categoriesHeaderMenu {
    position:absolute; /* remove */
}
```

Set your submenu `ul` class to the following:

```
.categoriesHeaderMenu ul {
    position:absolute; /* currently it is set as relative, change it to absolute */
    left:0;
}
```

Also, don't know if you noticed this but you're including your **jquery.superfishmenu.css** stylesheet and the js script for your menu under your submenu, that should be at the top on your header.